# Get field value from input to use it in Odoo

Tags: odoo, field

On the Website View,

How to get the value of "nbr1" field and copy it automatically in "Direct copy of nbr1" field ?

Does someone have an example, please ?

[image: test]

**template.xml**

```
  <template id="biography">
        <t t-call="website.layout">
            <t t-set="title">bio</t>
            <div class="oe_structure">
                <div class="container">
                    <h3 t-field="person.name"/>
                    <p>Last modified: <i t-field="person.write_date"/></p>                  
                    <p>nbr1 : <input type="number" name="nbr1"/></p>
                    <p>Direct copy of nbr1 : <h3 t-field="person.result"/></p>
                </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="oe_structure"/>
        </t>
    </template>
```

**model.py**

```
name = fields.Char()
nbr1 = fields.Integer()
result = fields.Integer(compute="_compute_total")    

@api.onchange('nbr1')
def _compute_total(self):
    for record in self:
        record.result = self.nbr1
```

Answer (score 0):

Give nbr1 in onchange function instead of biography.

```
name = fields.Char()
nbr1 = fields.Integer()
result = fields.Integer()    

@api.onchange('nbr1')
def _compute_total(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.nbr1:
            record.result = record.nbr1
```

Comment: hello @saks, I tried it, but its not working

Comment: Try the code i edited. Check whether it works or not. @Adri

Comment: Thank you @Saks_here for your answer, I tried your code, it created the result field in the database, but after changing the value of "nbr1" directly in the database its like its not going in the "_compute_total" function. So I changed this line: "result = fields.Integer(compute="_compute_total")" to go in the function, after refresh and keeping the same database the value was copied directly.  But when I change the value of nbr1 in the Web Field nothing happened. I though api.onchange should change the value on fly without refresh but its not doing it.

Comment: @adri actually when we use onchange, there is no need to call that function in xml using compute. If you want to copy the value directly without refreshing the page then you may try related=field_name

Comment: @adri try this code in py:                                          result = fields.Integer (related ='nbr1')

Comment: I tried this code and its work to copy the 'nbr1' in 'result' but I have to refresh the page. I would like to compute the value directly without refreshing the page do you things it possible ? I think refreshing is mandatory or detecting a click, an action etc...  because, It's not detecting when I clic on arrows in the integer fields on the website. At the end I would to compute 'nbr1' with another value like 'nbr2' field, compute it and display the value without refreshing.

Comment: Yes I tried this but it work after refreshing the page, but it doesn't work on the fly

Comment: Go through the link.. You may find an answer https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-can-i-copy-value-from-one-field-to-another-without-any-action-90182